# How to configure java.util.logging on Android?

Tags: android, logging

I want to use java.util.logging on Android. I want to configure the logging system with logging.properties. But how can I tell Android using the specific configure file? For example, I placed the logging.properties in the classpath root of the application. How Android knows the location of logging.properties.

Thanks

Answer (score 65):

This is now an FAQ for one of my projects, hopefully more people will find this here: java.util.logging works fine on Android. Please don't use anything else in your code, logging frameworks are like a pest in the Java world.

What is broken is the default logging handler shipped with Android, it ignores any log messages with level finer than INFO. You don't see DEBUG etc. messages.

The reason is the call to Log.isLoggable() in AndroidHandler.java:

https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_base/blob/master/core/java/com/android/internal/logging/AndroidHandler.java

Here is how you fix it:

```
import android.util.Log;
import java.util.logging.*;

/**
 * Make JUL work on Android.
 */
public class AndroidLoggingHandler extends Handler {

    public static void reset(Handler rootHandler) {
        Logger rootLogger = LogManager.getLogManager().getLogger("");
        Handler[] handlers = rootLogger.getHandlers();
        for (Handler handler : handlers) {
            rootLogger.removeHandler(handler);
        }
        rootLogger.addHandler(rootHandler);
    }

    @Override
    public void close() {
    }

    @Override
    public void flush() {
    }

    @Override
    public void publish(LogRecord record) {
        if (!super.isLoggable(record))
            return;

        String name = record.getLoggerName();
        int maxLength = 30;
        String tag = name.length() > maxLength ? name.substring(name.length() - maxLength) : name;

        try {
            int level = getAndroidLevel(record.getLevel());
            Log.println(level, tag, record.getMessage());
            if (record.getThrown() != null) {
                Log.println(level, tag, Log.getStackTraceString(record.getThrown()));
            }
        } catch (RuntimeException e) {
            Log.e("AndroidLoggingHandler", "Error logging message.", e);
        }
    }

    static int getAndroidLevel(Level level) {
        int value = level.intValue();

        if (value >= Level.SEVERE.intValue()) {
            return Log.ERROR;
        } else if (value >= Level.WARNING.intValue()) {
            return Log.WARN;
        } else if (value >= Level.INFO.intValue()) {
            return Log.INFO;
        } else {
            return Log.DEBUG;
        }
    }
}
```

In the main activity/initialization code of your application:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    AndroidLoggingHandler.reset(new AndroidLoggingHandler());
    java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger("my.category").setLevel(Level.FINEST);
...
```

**TL;DR:** Yes, you could use some magic properties, or adb shell command, or even learn how the stupid built-in logging handler's `DalvikLogging.loggerNameToTag` converts category names to tags (which you would have to do for those magic properties and shell commands), but why bother? Isn't logging painful enough?

Comment: By Android lifecycle, the best place to invoke this handler is onCreate() from a subclass of Application, and declare this class on manifest file.

Because if for some reason the main Activity doesn't appear (from a share, service, etc) the code still run.

Comment: @Renascienza no, you can't. Because at start of Application you will set level `Level.FINEST` , but when at first time you will call instance of MyClass `private static final Logger logger` it will have level == `Level.INFO`

Answer (score 5):

Generally one uses [android.util.Log](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/util/Log.html) for logging on Android. There are some key advantages to using that logger, such as being able to use `adb logcat` to view logging output sent to those logs.

You can try put logging.properties in `assets/` or `res/raw/`. If Android doesn't pick those up there, then one can use [java.util.logging.LogManager](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/logging/LogManager.html).[readConfiguration(java.io.InputStream)](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/logging/LogManager.html#readConfiguration(java.io.InputStream)) to force load it. (You can use the Resources and AssetManager classes to get the file as an InputStream).

Comment: Thank you very much. This approach does well. Now I have to struggle to write log to sdcard.

Comment: @tangjie not sure what your final goal is, but I would consider buffering logs in your app and then send them to a server where you actually have access to

Answer (score 2):

At least on Android 4.3, with unchanged Handler, if you use

```
adb shell setprop log.tag.YOURTAG DEBUG
```

You can see messages logged with up to Level.FINE in logcat. I haven't figured out a way to log higher levels, but that's sufficient for me.

Answer (score 2):

In case one of you only wants to route java.util.logging output from third party libraries, this can achieved pretty easily with SLF4J and its [jul-to-slf4j bridge](http://www.slf4j.org/legacy.html#jul-to-slf4j). This works for `FINE` and `FINEST` log statements, too, BTW.

Here's the maven dependency

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
    <artifactId>jul-to-slf4j</artifactId>
    <version>${slf4j.version}</version>
</dependency>
```

To bootstrap it, put the following in your `Application` class, [Roboguice](https://github.com/roboguice/roboguice) Module or somewhere else where it gets executed before your first log statement. (Configuring this in `assets/logging.properties`seems not to work, unfortunately).

```
/*
 * add SLF4JBridgeHandler to j.u.l's root logger, should be done once
 * during the initialization phase of your application
 */
SLF4JBridgeHandler.install();
```

You can then either

- configure all your log statements from `assets/logback.xml` (using [logback-android](https://github.com/tony19/logback-android)). See [here](http://www.slf4j.org/api/org/slf4j/bridge/SLF4JBridgeHandler.html) for a mapping of log levels.
- or just use [SLF4J-android](http://www.slf4j.org/android/) to forward the log statements to logcat. To do so, just put the following dependency to your classpath, no further  config required:

  ```
  <dependency>
      <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
      <artifactId>slf4j-android</artifactId>
      <version>${slf4j.version}</version>
  </dependency>
  ```

I implemented this successfully using

```
<properties>
    <slf4j.version>1.7.6</slf4j.version>
</properties>
```

**Note**:

- Please read the part of the [jul-to-slf4j](http://www.slf4j.org/legacy.html#jul-to-slf4j) doc that relates to **performance** carefully!
- If you use the [LogcatAppender](http://tony19.github.io/logback-android/doc/1.1.1-3/ch/qos/logback/classic/android/LogcatAppender.html) make sure to keep in mind that the JUL log messages (except the ones with level finer than `INFO`) are routed to logcat by android. So make sure to apply appropriate filters that avoid duplicates.

Comment: It works but for me log messages with levels finer than INFO were not shown with adb logcat (slf4j 1.7.21).

Answer (score 2):

Here is modified [answer of Christian Bauer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9047282/2425851)

If somewhere in any third party lib you will see something like this:

```
   final public class AnyClass {        
        private static final Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(AnyClass.class.getName());
         ...
            if (logger.isLoggable(Level.FINE)) {
                logger.fine("any log event");
            }
         ...
     }
```

Add to your code this after creating first instance of `AnyClass.class`:

```
SetupLogger.setup(Arrays.asList(
                new Pair<>(AnyClass.class.getName(), Level.FINEST),//AnyClass.class.getName() is because instance `logger` has his name
                new Pair<>(AnyOther.class.getName(), Level.FINEST)
        ));
```

SetupLogger .class

```
public class SetupLogger {

    static public void setup(List<Pair<String, Level>> loggerNames) {
        // suppress the logging output to the console
        AndroidLoggingHandler rootHandler = new AndroidLoggingHandler();
        AndroidLoggingHandler.reset(rootHandler );
        for (Pair<String, Level> pair : loggerNames) {
            Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(pair.first);
            logger.setLevel(pair.second);
        }
    }
}
```