# Logging in "Java Library Code" libs for Android applications

Tags: java, android, logging

I follow the [advice](http://www.sonatype.com/books/mvnref-book/reference/android-dev-sect-using.html#android-dev-sect-multimodule) to implement Android device (not application!) independent library code for my Android Apps in a seperate "Java Library Code" project. This makes testing easier for me as I can use the standard maven project layout, Spring test support and Continuous Build systems the way I am used to. I do not want to mix this inside my Android App project although this might be possible.

I now wonder how to implement logging in this library. As this library will be used on the Android device I would like to go with `android.util.Log`. I added the followind dependency to my project to get the missing Android packages/classes and dependencies:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.google.android</groupId>
    <artifactId>android</artifactId>
    <version>2.2.1</version>
    <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
```

But this library just contains stub method (similar to the android.jar inside the android-sdk), thus using `android.util.Log` results in

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Stub!
```

when running my unit tests. How do I implement logging which works on the Android device but does not fail outside (I do not expect it to work, but it must not fail)?

Thanks for any advice
  Klaus

---

For now I am going with the workaround to catch the exception outside android but hope there is a better solution.

```
try {
    Log.d("me", "hello");
} catch (RuntimeException re) {
    // ignore failure outside android
}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

These two links to a mirror of the android open source project ([1](https://github.com/aosp-mirror/platform_frameworks_base/blob/master/core/java/com/android/internal/logging/AndroidHandler.java), [2](https://github.com/aosp-mirror/platform_frameworks_base/blob/master/core/java/com/android/internal/logging/AndroidConfig.java)) seem to suggest that that the default Handler of java.util.Logging on android delegates to android.util.Log, so in your library you should be able to just use java.util.logging apis.

I could not find any further documentation regarding this behaviour

Comment: This works fine! Will now use java.util.logging the first time after so many years of Java development......

Comment: Note: Android by default only shows INFO level or above. For more information: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4561345/how-to-configure-java-util-logging-on-android?noredirect=1&lq=1

Comment: The above mentioned Links (GrepCode) are dead

Answer (score 4):

You can use this snippet:

```
java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger("SOME_TAG").log(Level.INFO, "log message")
```

And it will look like this in android logger:

```
2019-03-12 14:14:20.143 31195-32138/your.package.name I/SOME_TAG: log message
```

Comment: Note: Android by default only shows INFO level or above. For more information: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4561345/how-to-configure-java-util-logging-on-android?noredirect=1&lq=1

Answer (score 1):

This works everywhere:

```
java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger("YOUR_TAG").log(java.util.logging.Level.INFO, "message");
```