# How configure/load Logging.properties on android?

Tags: java, android, logging, mobile

How configure/load Logging.properties on android ? I reviewed about the class android.util.Log, and I can display information on LogCat console, but I don't found how to make/load a custom "Logging.properties" on my application. more exactly I need is define the file name and its path, to write the log output. It is possible ? any of you, could provide me, where could find this information ? or where I can found a tutorial about "How configure the Logging.properties on android" ?

Comment: Same here. I found on http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4561345/how-to-configure-java-util-logging-on-android that a simple sdcard file writing should be easy with logging.properties, but I can't find out how