# Using java.util.logging.Logger in a jar file that will be displayed in LogCat in Android

Tags: java, android, logging, java.util.logging

```
Android Studio 0.8.1
java version "1.7.0_60"
```

Hello,

I have created a jar file and calling this from my Android App. For testing purposed I want to put some logging in the jar file that will be displayed in the LogCat window.

I have decided to use Java's `java.util.logging.Logger` class. However, when I run my app with `No Filter` I cannot see any of my log messages being displayed.

```
import java.util.logging.ConsoleHandler;
import java.util.logging.SimpleFormatter;
import java.util.logging.Handler;
import java.util.logging.Logger;
import java.util.logging.Level;

public class RequestFactory extends WebServiceRequestFactory {
    private static final Logger log = Logger.getLogger("RequestFactory");

    public RequestFactory() {
        ConsoleHandler consoleHandler = new ConsoleHandler();
        log.addHandler(consoleHandler);
        consoleHandler.setFormatter(new SimpleFormatter());

        log.log(Level.FINE, "LOG: Initialized overloaded constructor");
        System.out.println("Initialized overloaded constructor");
    }
    .....
```

I have set the above to be displayed in the Console. However, the `System.out.println` always prints out. However, I don't want to use the System.out.println for displaying logs messages.

If possible I would like to stick to java's logging class.

In the LogCat window I can see the `System.out.println(...)`, but not the `log.log(...)` one:

```
I/System.out﹕ Initialized overloaded constructor
```

Am I doing something wrong here?

Many thanks for any suggestions

Comment: Why not use Android's [`Log`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/util/Log.html) directly? -- Have you seen http://stackoverflow.com/a/9047282/1015327 ?

Comment: Because I am creating a jar with has a multi-platform purpose and don't want to import any android classes into it.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to configure java.util.logging on Android?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4561345/how-to-configure-java-util-logging-on-android)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The default level for the [ConsoleHandler](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/logging/ConsoleHandler.html) is INFO.  The default level for the [logger](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/logging/Logger.html) is inherited from its parent.  By default, the root logger is usually set to INFO.  A FINE log message will not be reported using the default settings.  Change the log level of the ConsoleHandler to ALL and change the level of the logger to FINE.

```
log.setLevel(Level.FINE);
consoleHandler.setLevel(Level.ALL);
```