# Show java.util.logging.Logger logs in Android Studio logcat

Tags: java, android, logging, logcat

I need to watch the log from socket.io-client-java in Android Studio logcat. For example: https://github.com/socketio/socket.io-client-java/blob/master/src/main/java/io/socket/client/IO.java#L70

1. Why don't I see the output of `logger.fine(String.format("ignoring socket cache for %s", source));` in the logcat?
2. The logger in the above example is set to `Fine`, but in Android Studio logcat there is no `Fine` level (only `Verbose`, `Debug`, `Info`, `Warn`, `Error`, `Assert`). How to translate the level from `java.util.logging.Logger` to Android Studio logcat?

Comment: Did you find any solution?

Comment: No, but if it's interesting to you too, you can vote up this question

Answer (score 14, accepted):

OK, Logcat doesn't show it because default logger level is info.

Here is solution that works for me very well. I debug socket.io now in main activity

```
                import io.socket.client.Manager;
                import io.socket.client.Socket;
                @Override
                    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
                        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
                        AndroidLoggingHandler.reset(new AndroidLoggingHandler());           
                        java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(Socket.class.getName()).setLevel(Level.FINEST);
                        java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(io.socket.engineio.client.Socket.class.getName()).setLevel(Level.FINEST); 
                        java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(Manager.class.getName()).setLevel(Level.FINEST);
                        }
```

**Possible util class**

```
import android.util.Log;
import java.util.logging.*;
public class AndroidLoggingHandler extends Handler {

    public static void reset(Handler rootHandler) {
        Logger rootLogger = LogManager.getLogManager().getLogger("");
        Handler[] handlers = rootLogger.getHandlers();
        for (Handler handler : handlers) {
            rootLogger.removeHandler(handler);
        }
        LogManager.getLogManager().getLogger("").addHandler(rootHandler);
    }

    @Override
    public void close() {
    }

    @Override
    public void flush() {
    }

    @Override
    public void publish(LogRecord record) {
        if (!super.isLoggable(record))
            return;

        String name = record.getLoggerName();
        int maxLength = 30;
        String tag = name.length() > maxLength ? name.substring(name.length() - maxLength) : name;

        try {
            int level = getAndroidLevel(record.getLevel());
            Log.println(level, tag, record.getMessage());
            if (record.getThrown() != null) {
                Log.println(level, tag, Log.getStackTraceString(record.getThrown()));
            }
        } catch (RuntimeException e) {
            Log.e("AndroidLoggingHandler", "Error logging message.", e);
        }
    }

    static int getAndroidLevel(Level level) {
        int value = level.intValue();
        if (value >= 1000) {
            return Log.ERROR;
        } else if (value >= 900) {
            return Log.WARN;
        } else if (value >= 800) {
            return Log.INFO; 
        } else {
            return Log.DEBUG;
        }
    }
}
```

here is original answer:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/9047282/5127756